# MS Windows batch file: need for-loop over multiple lines

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch file to delete unwanted folders; its commands need to have a limited width.

Here's what I have that's working, but is too long:

```
for /d /r . %%d in (Debug,.vs) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
```

This version should work based on what I'm seeing on other pages here, but it isn't:

```
for /d /r . %%d in (Debug,.vs) do ^
   @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
```

Its output is

```
C:\Project1>for / %d in (Debug .vs) do    @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d" 

C:\Project1>   @if exist "C:\Project1\Debug" rd /s/q "C:\Project1\Debug" 
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

C:\Project1>   @if exist "C:\Project1\.vs" rd /s/q "C:\Project1\.vs" 
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

C:\Project1>for / %d in (Debug .vs) do    @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d" 
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

C:\Project1>   @if exist "C:\Project1\Debug" rd /s/q "C:\Project1\Debug" 
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

C:\Project1>   @if exist "C:\\.vs" rd /s/q "C:\Project1\.vs" 
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

...
```

I also tried a variant without the ^:

```
for /d /r . %%d in (Debug,.vs) do (
   @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
)
```

This does actually delete things, but it also gives some weird output:

```
C:\Project1>for / %d in (Debug .vs) do    @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d" 

C:\Project1> ()

C:\Project1> ()

C:\Project1> ()

C:\Project1> ()

...
```

Just taking the ()'s off gives me "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Why is a single line (like your very first example) an issue? First, it's not that long - it fits within a standard sized command window width). Second, why is the length of that line relevant at all? If you have a single line that is working, wasting a bunch of time and effort to shorten that single line seems pretty illogical. (Well, I guess if you're working on an old 320x240 resolution screen, that line might be too long. Still not sure it's worth the effort you're putting into changing it, even in that case.)

Comment: Because I have to publish it in a venue with large font and limited page width.

Comment: @TopologicalSort, how many characters do you envisage being your maximum per line?

Comment: I was able to get by with this many (easier to show than counting): `for /r . %%d in (Debug,.vs) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"`. But I was happy to find other options (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste lines in the CMD prompt that are longer than what is displayed it just scrolls to the right (or left depending on how you view it)

However, you are using `%%` in your variable names, which means you must be running this inside a CMD/BAT Script.  Which will allow even longer line lengths.

So this should be fine:

```
REM Single Line:
FOR /R %%D in (Debug,.vs) DO @( ECHO Checking: "%%~D" &  IF EXIST "%%~D" ( ECHO. Found! - Removing: "%%~D" ... & RD /S /Q "%%~D" ) )
```

Or Smaller if you really need it:

```
REM Even Smaller Single Line:
FOR /R %%D in (Debug,.vs) DO @(IF EXIST "%%~D" (RD /S/Q "%%~D"))
```

Smaller - ignore non-existent directory errors

```
REM Even Smaller Single Line:
FOR /R %%D in (Debug,.vs) DO @(RD /S/Q "%%~D") 2>Nul
```

**The Smallest single line, but the output will look pretty messy**

```
REM Even Smaller Single Line:
FOR /R %%D in (Debug,.vs) DO (RD/S/Q "%%D")
```

Now if for whatever reason you want to make this as small as possible and you are working inside of a cmd script, you can put carriage returns after every Open and close Paren, and you can put carriage returns between terms in your criteria.

Multi-Line:

```
FOR /R %%D in (
 Debug
 .vs
) DO @(
 ECHO Checking: "%%~D" 
 IF EXIST "%%~D" (
  ECHO. Found! - Removing: "%%~D" ...
  RD /S /Q "%%~D"
 )
)
```

For whatever reason, almost no one does the above on their criteria, but it's a completely valid option.

Shortest Lines in a multi-line file that are Possible:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R %%D in (
Debug
.vs
) DO (
RD /S /Q "%%~D"
)
```

And Are is at the CMD CLI versions If you trust you can paste more than you can see:

```
FOR /R %D in (Debug,.vs) DO @( ECHO Checking: "%~D" &  IF EXIST "%~D" ( ECHO. Found! - Removing: "%~D" ... & RD /S /Q "%~D" ) )
```

And Smaller if you can't:

```
FOR /R %D in (Debug,.vs) DO @(IF EXIST "%~D" (RD/S/Q "%D")
```

And as I mentioned before YOU CAN use the same method of putting in carriage returns for a direct paste into the CMD prompt, people generally don't because it is more likely to break on paste into the cmd prompt, but your requirement's code is fairly simple, so it is totally valid to paste it into the CMD Prompt directly:

**Smallest Multi-Line CMD-Prompt Version of the original:**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R %D in (
Debug
.vs
) DO @(
RD /S/Q "%~D"
)
```

Also, you only need to use `FOR /R %D`, when you write `FOR /D /R . %D` CMD will simply ignore the /D and change to /R syntax, likewise the . is not needed because it is implied you are using `.` if there is no base directory chosen.

Leaving off the unnecessary Characters will save you an extra three characters :)

`FOR /R` automatically walks the directory tree, while `/D` has to be forced to do so by using a wild card, while adding `/R` after `/D` essentially causes the For loop to ignore the `/D` and use `/R` syntax instead, and only differs if you use wildcards (which you do not).

## Furthermore:

As I was mentioning to another member in the comments originally, there are more expedient methods to find directories with `.vs` or `debug` using `DIR` which will be much faster to list them, and `FindStr` which will be much faster to find them than testing if they exist.

I didn't have time last night due to a needless discussion with that member as to why adding `/D` to my listed commands was not necessary, However, I will place the first draft of those here.

This is the smallest Maximum required Length possible without variable substitution off the cuff (Length of 25 Characters) and can be run at the CMD Line:

**Smallest CMD-LINE FindStr v off the cuff without substitution (Len 25):**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN (
'DIR
  /AD/B/S
^|
 FINDStr /I /R
  /C:"\\\.vs$"
  /C:"\\debug$"
') DO @( RD/S/Q "%A")
```

Actually, there is one other thing we can do which gets it down to the same max Size as the previous command (Len 14) that isn't technically using Variable substitution, we can wrap it in another FOR /F Loop.

The extra loop is only printing and could be set to do nothing which would make it faster, but the inner loop or outer loop can do the deleting (I chose inner loop)

**Smallest CMD-LINE FindStr v Using a second Loop without variable Substitution (Len 14):**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %a IN (
'FOR /F
"UseBackQ"
%A IN (
`DIR
/AD/B/S
^^^|
FINDStr /I /R
/C:"\\\.vs$"
/C:"\\debug$"
`^) DO @(
ECHO."%A"
RD /Q/S "%A"
^) ') DO @(
ECHO.Gone: %a)
```

**If we want to get into Variable Substitution, then the minimum line length is probably about 10 Characters.**

Will post that later still

Comment: @Compo, I didn't even see it, I was busy editing, so it seems I just brushed right over it, however you happen to be incorrect on this matter. `FOR /D` is a file Search by default, `FOR /R` is a Directory Tree Walk by default.  20 years of CMD scripting on and I couldn't see how you Could mistake the `/D` as being required I guess.  While `/D` with a Wildcard can also match Directories, `FOR /R` can't match files, except in the case of a Wildcard, so, yes If he was using Wildcards then this would be a problem, and /D /R would be necessary..

Comment: @Compo, but at that point you would probably do better to use DIR and match it anyway, (even now that might be preferable) instead of tesing if every file exists just return the ones that do:  `FOR /F "Tokens=*" %D IN ('DIR /AD/B/S  * ^| FINDStr /R /C:"debug" /C:".vs"') DO @(ECHO.%~D)`

Comment: @Compo I noted that already, in the reply to you over 1 hour ago, so I'm not sure why you're talking to me as if I was the OP, is the confusion?  I simply wanted to write the shortest lines possible to meet OP's need as that is what he was saying was his goal, I'm working on a more interesting problem on another site where I spend more time than stack, but as I wrote an hour ago, using FindStr would be faster, as using DIR which is faster at enumerating directories than a FOR /D or FOR /R, so it would be preferable Unless you are character constrained as th OP stated.

Comment: @Compo Essentially that was the FUn part of this Q, how can I limit lengths of lines, even if I do question the OPs need to do so.  You know?  Go with the Interesting bit. :)

Comment: That's a fair point, although you seem intent on ignoring everything said here so far, so I'm no sure if you will notice that I acknowledge using the \ as being preferable.

Comment: On the multiline I was striving for Shortests Max Length, not shortest each line, which would seem to be the preferable medium for readability, however I am beginning to feel that this is some sort of deliberate attack and aI ask tat you please withdraw from badgering needlessly.  Thanks. the ~D is true however,in the single line version, but not the multi-lines as those are anything less than 14 characters, as that is the minimum max length without variable substitution which can actually reduce all of the lines further but it was becoming splitting hairs and over obfuscation of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195312/discussion-between-ben-personick-and-compo).

Comment: I think it's a great public service to display all these options! And I'm happy to have them, even if I am unlikely to need them again. As it turned out, I went with just dropping the /D. But if my page had been a little narrower, I'd have used one of the breaking-over-command-line options.

Comment: Glad to help, as I mentioned in the original responses here I would suggest using DIR /AD/S/B|FINDStr/I "\.vs .debug"

Comment: @TopologicalSort Glad to help, as I mentioned in the original responses here I would suggest using `DIR /AD/S/B|FINDStr/I /C:".vs" /C:"debug"` as it's more efficient but I could see it was going to take more effort to compact it short so I didn't bother as I got into some long back and forth here with a member who was confused into thinking the `/D` was required for your original code.  I might post that in on this too as an addendum, but either way, very happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your latest code, `for /r . %%d in (Debug,.vs) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"`, is not the most efficient method. It appends `\Debug` and `\.vs` to every subdirectory of the current directory then passes each of those, *(2 per subdirectory)*, through an `If Exist` command before issuing the `RD` command against those which exist. There is no specific statement to determine whether that which exists is a directory. For instance an extensionless file named `debug` would currently pass to your `RD` command. This can easily be rectified by adding a trailing backslash, `for /r . %%d in (Debug,.vs) do @if exist "%%d\" rd /s/q "%%d"`. That however would add another character to your command, which could be negated by removing the default current directory specification to `For`'s `/R` option, *as explained in Ben's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694628)*, e.g. `for /r %%d in (Debug,.vs) do @if exist "%%d\" rd /s/q "%%d"`.

Now you have shown us that your maximum is somewhere between `60` and `62` characters per line, *(initial line character length was `63`, latest is `60`)*, I thought that I'd provide some `Dir` example code:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
 'Dir /B/S/AD Debug .vs 2^>NUL'
)Do @RD /S/Q "%%A" 2>NUL
```

Using `FindStr` could also, *as suggested in Ben's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694464/ms-windows-batch-file-need-for-loop-over-multiple-lines#comment99955566_56694628)*, provide an alternative solution:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
 'Dir /B/S/AD 2^>NUL^|FindStr /I "\\Debug$ \\\.vs$"'
)Do @RD /S/Q "%%A" 2>NUL
```

There is one trivial thing to note with the above, it is feasible that a subdirectory named either `Debug` or `.vs` could exist as a subdirectory of either `Debug` or `.vs`. *It seems a little silly to potentially pass a sibling belonging to an already removed subdirectory to another remove process*. To prevent that, *although not speed tested, I cannot see it being much slower, if at all, over my previous example*, it could be piped through a second `FindStr` command:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
 Dir /B/S/AD-L-S 2^>NUL^|^
 FindStr /I "\\Debug$ \\\.vs$"^|^
 FindStr /IV "\\Debug\\ \\\.vs\\"
')Do @RD /S/Q "%%A" 2>NUL
```

The above example also adds additional security to filter away any potential system directories and reparse points too.

*Although all of the above solutions are clearly longer than `60` characters, I've kept them all within that maximum line limit, whilst trying to try to maintain balance and readability.*

Comment: I appreciate the options, and hope others looking for help will find this as well.